# Good C/C++ compiler for OpenSolaris for x86

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, solaris

I am using OpenSolaris on x86. I tried the gcc compiler for Solaris [for free](http://sunfreeware.com/), but found it to be quite old (gcc 3.4.6). I want to know if there is any latest C++ compiler for OpenSolaris, that is similar to gcc. What is the best compiler out there for x86 with Solaris?

Comment: Isn't OpenSolaris pretty much dead?  Use Solaris instead and then you can use Oracle Solaris Studio.

Comment: unless -- depending on your goals -- you dont have the money. or want a more standards compliant compiler. or want c++11 features.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing is more similar to GCC than GCC... The GNU people have some answers for you:

http://gcc.gnu.org/install/binaries.html

If none of those binaries are useful, Google found for me:

http://www.dev-eth0.de/compile-gcc-4-on-opensolaris

Why haven't you found a good guide like that and run with it? It's not all that difficult to build GCC, it just takes a while.

Answer (score 2):

Sun Studio - contain not only compiler but very good NetBeans based IDE and set of debugging and profiling tools

Comment: Neither Sun or Oracle have [listed support](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/overview/index-jsp-139533.html) for OpenSolaris with Sun ONE/Oracle Solaris studio.

Comment: OpenSolaris itself was built on OpenSolaris using the Studio compiler, it was actually requiring it. This is quite a good hint about support. http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Community+Group+tools/sun_studio_tools http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Community+Group+tools/sun_studio_tools

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to follow my tutorial, you can try

`pkg install gcc-43`

which will install a 4.3.2 GCC

Answer (score 0):

use oracle solaris studio or gcc higher versions.